# why the function of qcomboBox is not working?

Tags: qt, combobox

I am new to Qt and I was experimenting with the functions of the `QComboBox` class. I have written the following code:

```cpp
ui->comboBox->addItem("matk");
ui->comboBox->addItem("john");
```

This added the names to the `comboBox`, then follows

```cpp
ui->comboBox->setMinimumContentLenght;
```

which caused the error:

> no matching function for call to `QComboBox::setMinimumContestsLenght()`

Why?

Comment: In the question, you didn't write `setMinimumContentLenght()` (with parentheses), is this the same as in your code?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing:   `ui->comboBox->setMinimumContentLenght;` but setMinimumContentLenght is actually a `setter method` taking a parameter, you are using it instead as some kind of field...

do instead like in the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#minimumContentsLength-prop) explained

```
ui->comboBox->setMinimumContentLenght(x);
```

where x is an integer